# Navigation links are not returned when using JSON for OData (using Apache Olingo for Java)

Tags: java, json, apache, odata, olingo

when using the below code using XML it works perfectly, that is, the navigation links are returned successfully.  However, when I change the format to "json" or "application/json", the links2 navigation links list is empty, meaning that rental.getNavigations() returns an empty list.

Can anyone help please? I am using Apache Olingo for Java OData v4.

Thanks

```
URI uri = client.newURIBuilder(serviceRoot)
                 .appendEntitySetSegment("Rentals")
                 .appendKeySegment(1).format("application/xml").build();

ODataRetrieveResponse<ODataEntity> response2 = client.getRetrieveRequestFactory().getEntityRequest(uri).execute();
ODataEntity rental = response2.getBody();

        List<ODataLink> links2 = rental.getNavigationLinks();
        for (ODataLink link : links2) {
            System.out.println(link.getRel());
            System.out.println(link.getName());
            URI linkUri = client.newURIBuilder(serviceRoot)
                      .appendNavigationSegment(link.getLink().toString()).format("atom").build();
            ODataRetrieveResponse<ODataEntity> responseCustomer
                    = client.getRetrieveRequestFactory().getEntityRequest(linkUri).execute();
            ODataEntity cust = responseCustomer.getBody();
            if(link.getName().equals("Stock"))
                System.out.println(cust.getProperty("Status").getValue().toString()); 
            else System.out.println(cust.getProperty("Name").getValue().toString()); 
       }
```

Comment: Hi @user3423878. If my answer below has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: When adding the odata.metadata=full format option, the OData service outputs an exception message which states that the service does not accept metadata=full format.  Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 1):

The [`odata.metadata=full`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/errata02/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-errata02-os-complete.html#_Toc403940606) format parameter is necessary to get [`odata.navigationLink`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/errata02/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-errata02-os-complete.html#_Annotation_odata.navigationLink_and_1) properties to appear in the JSON response. Add `odata.metadata=full` to the format option when building the `client`. The full format should be `application/json;odata.metadata=full`. If you have access to the request headers via the `client` object, you might consider setting the `Accept` header instead.